Find which process is using hwrng
I cant work out a way to know which process is using hwrng which is using ~ 100% CPU.  Any ideas how to trace it?  Tried all the regulars lsof, ps unless theres a command line i havent worked out.

# lsof -p 62
COMMAND PID USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
hwrng    62 root  cwd       DIR  179,2     4096    2 /
hwrng    62 root  rtd       DIR  179,2     4096    2 /
hwrng    62 root  txt   unknown                      /proc/62/exe

# lsof | grep hwrng
hwrng       62                            root  cwd       DIR              179,2      4096          2 /
hwrng       62                            root  rtd       DIR              179,2      4096          2 /
hwrng       62                            root  txt   unknown                                         /proc/62/exe

# strace -ewrite -p 62
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, 62): Operation not permitted



Please attache any error output of dmesg to your original question.

Please tag your question with operating system, and name distro and version in the question. I will assume Linux given a task named systemd, but that should not require reading screenshot images.
